# Updating the DOM after success Ajax call on a infinite scroll generated content ordered by newest

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So, basically i have an Ajax call that triggers on scroll and loads comments from a PHP script and orders them by "ID DESC" (fairly basic infinite scrolling).

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop()==$(document).height()-$(window).height()){
     Ajax call here that appends the comments on success.
     The offset get incremented every time.
  }
 })
```

My question is how to handle a new comment? When someone sends a new comment another Ajax call fires, the comment gets inserted in the database, etc.
Now if no comments are loaded and the users scrolls, his comment will be displayed first or among the first since they are Ordered by ID or DATE DESC.

But if there are comments already loaded how do make his comment appear first, so the user can see his comment, do i make another Ajax call after the user comments that loads only that comment? Do i reload all the comments again? Do i need to to something different from PHP, or is this not a good way to go about  something like this?

Comment: There are things like append, after, prepend and before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can effectively trigger a new ajax call after the comment submission /save and reload only the latest(s) one, displaying them with [`.prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) at the beginning of the comments list. (I assumed that you use jQuery because of $. but let me know if I'm wrong :) ).
To show that new comments are displayed at the beginning, an highlight effect could be nice to make the list modification noticeable.

I would not recommend to load all comments after submission, it would make no sense if you already have them displayed. Let's avoid to download useless data (useless for you already have them). :)